# How should I bond my CSST given my gas entry distant from my electrical entry?

Tags: electrical, propane, csst

I live in VA and used 3/4" CSST to run 5ft from LP Tank up the inside of the wall to the first floor's floor joists, then switch to 3/4" black pipe to run 72 inches to the kitchen where the range is, switch back to 1 ft of 3/4" CSST to bend up through floor plate, which connects to shut-off valve, then 1/2" CSST to connect with the range.

Do I need to bond this, and if so what is the best/easiest way?  My propane tank and the new CSST I installed is on the other side of the house opposite the electrric box and outside electric meter.

Some options I have thought of, or were suggested to me:

- do nothing, as CSST is bonded anyway if CSST fittings are tightened all the way
- do nothing, as CSST isn't that long, and VA has no CODE requirement for VA
- install grounding rods next to propane tank and bond to that (do rods need to connect with electrical panel?)
- dig a trench all around the house to lay ground wire to connect with outside bonding clamp
- try to snake wire 6AWG wire through the house somehow to the electrical panel

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only my feeling.  Sparks and propane do not mix well.  If you can limit sparks go for it, but don't kill your wallet.

Comment: _Shudders_ seeing permanent deformation happening in that piece of vinyl siding bent out of the corner post. (I'm in the middle of residing my house - I'm very aware of vinyl siding issues right now...)

Comment: Back to the question asked... This is an _additional_ line not the _only_ line, correct? Would it be reasonable to presume that the _other_ part of the gas line is _already_ grounded? If so, I'd think that the grounding on the other branch should be sufficient. I'm no expert, so this is a comment/question, not an answer...

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer, but answers some of your points.  From a 2015 International Code Council article on "[bonding of corrugated stainless steel tubing (CSST) piping system](https://abihomeservices.com/download/CodeNotes_2015IFGC.pdf) "

Why bond? Because potential differences can cause arcing to and then holes in the thin-walled CSST:

> The bonding of CSST piping
> system to the grounding electrode system of the structure in
> which the CSST is installed will lower the voltage build-up on
> the CSST caused by unintentional energizing from outside
> sources such as power surges and lightning strikes. The
> bonding will help achieve an equi-potential state between the
> CSST and other similarly bonded metallic systems (such as
> the water piping, structural steel, electrical raceways and coax
> cable). The bonding will help reduce the possibility and severity
> of arcing between these conductive systems when energized by
> a lightning strike on or nearby the premises.

The point is to equalize potential among the various metal systems, not necessarily to have the CSST match ground potential.

**Thus, "A separate grounding electrode
and grounding system cannot be established just for the fuel
gas piping system"** (your headline question)

Clamp/bond requirements:

- "The bonding clamp can
  be located at any location within the piping system. "
- "The bonding conductor must be not longer than 75 feet "
- "The corrugated stainless steel tubing itself must never be used as a
  point of attachment of the bonding clamp."
- "The clamp can be attached to a length of rigid pipe, a malleable
  iron pipe fitting, a prefabricated manifold, or a brass CSST
  fitting."
- "The bonding clamp must
  be accessible and can be located outdoors or indoors."
- "Only a single point of attachment is required regardless of the
  length or complexity of the piping system. "

Now, if your gas line is connected to an appliance that also has an electrical connection, it will likely thus be indirectly connected to the appliance's equipment grounding conductor. Such a connection won't meet the requirements above, but in practice it may suffice to give most or all of the anti-arcing benefit.

Comment: Good find. It sounds like adding a grounding strap from the 6' black pipe in the middle of the run to a convenient, local, ground wire _might_ do the trick.